# How do I arrange the items into a list and assign?

Tags: python, split, variable-assignment, string-length

In the comments, I have written some pseudocode to remind myself of what to do. So far, I know how to split and find the length of the string. But after that, I don't know how to arrange the items into a list and assign that list to a variable.

Below is an example of what I think it is:

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"

# split: split original string into several strings
# find len(gth) of each small string
# assign answer = to num_words_list

original_str.split()
for i in original_str.split():
    len(i)
    i = i + 1
num_words_list = len(i)
print(num_words_list)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to split the string, store it in a list and find it's length.  You just use below code.

```
str_list = original_str.split()
num_words_list = len(str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be using `i` for the length as well. Just use a separate variable instead:

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"

num_words_list = 0
for i in original_str.split():
    lengthOfString += len(i)
print(num_words_list)
```

Also you can just use the original string instead of counting each word, a simple `replace` should do:

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"

num_words_list = len(original_str.replace(" ", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the length of each word in a list you can use this code

```
num_words_list = []
for word in original_str.split():
    num_words_list.append(len(word))

print(num_words_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question as asked is not completely clear; but my interpretation is that you want `num_words_list` to be equal to a list of the length of each word in the original string.

I would solve this problem functionally, because it can be done really concisely. The `string` method `split` returns a list of sub-strings delineated by the indicated string or white-spaces by default. So, if you want the length of each of these sub-strings, then we will just pass them as an argument with the `len` function to `map`:

```
original_str = "The quick brown rhino jumped over the extremely lazy fox"

words = original_str.split()

# Importantly, we wrap the map function in the list function to convert it 
# because map returns a map object
num_words_list = list(map(len, words))

print(num_words_list)
```

This will print out a list of integers enumerating the length of each word (since we are splitting on default white-spaces). The `map` function applies the supplied function to each element in the supplied iterable, mapping each element in the iterable, if you will. In our case, we took our list of strings and mapped them to integers using the `len` function.